# Adding Yarn to Heroku build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, yarnpkg, webpacker

I know there are a number of ways to approach this but I'm trying to set this up the "right" way that'll work over time in each environment.

Recently migrated Rails app's JS dependency mgmt from Bower to Yarn. Everything happy in DEV, TEST, and CI, but when pushing to Heroku we get:

```
[Scout] [02/07/19 22:07:56 +0000 run.9437 (2674)] INFO : Deferring agent start. Standing by for first request
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: glidejs/dist/css/glide.core.min.
Load paths:
     /tmp/build_add2bb9351c2d549635720a6c5b13bfb/app/assets/images
```

OK, Heroku says box needs Yarn. I can force that...but it has been declared in `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "yarn": ">= 1.0.0"
},
```

Assumed, wrongfully, that would be picked up.

Digging deeper I see in [Heroku's notes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#installed-binaries) that

> Applications that have the webpacker gem will get a default version of Yarn

But we're not yet reliant on Webpack(er). Soon. But not yet.

Thoughts? Just add webpacker gem and walk away? or another solution. Really just trying to visualize the chain(s) of command here.

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming since you were using Bower that the Node Buildpack was already added to your Heroku config? In which order are they added?

Comment: No, Ruby is only thing in buildpack.

Comment: try installing the Node Buildpack and place it in first position in your Buildpack list, have a look at this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#adding-a-buildpack